# if i use old firebase in new play console will it be closed?

Tags: google-play-console

If I use the firebase of my closed play console account on the console I just opened, is there a chance that my account will be closed? I will be glad if experienced friends can help.

If I use the firebase of my closed play console account on the console I just opened, is there a chance that my account will be closed? I will be glad if dexperienced friends can help.